# Override pdf fields in new document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have one pdf template, which I try to override in new document. I need to get some fields from template PDF and re-write their values in new PDF. I do this :

```
PdfReader templatereader = new PdfReader("Templates//PDF_Template_Empty.pdf");
PdfDocument template = new PdfDocument(templatereader);
var writer = new PdfWriter(OutputFilepath);
PdfDocument newreport = new PdfDocument(writer);
var fields = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(template, true); //!!!
```

But then i catch the Exception :

> iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'There is no associate PdfWriter for making
>   indirects.'

What i am doing wrong and how to fix it ? iTextsharp 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error explains exactly what goes wrong: you didn't define a `PdfWriter` instance for the `PdfDocument` instance named `template`. You create a `PdfWriter` instance for `newreport`, but you never use `newreport`.

This is how it should be done:

```
PdfReader templatereader = new PdfReader("Templates//PDF_Template_Empty.pdf");
var writer = new PdfWriter(OutputFilepath);
PdfDocument template = new PdfDocument(templatereader, writer);
var fields = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(template, true);
```

As you can see, there is no need for the `newreport` instance. The `template` instance takes the `templatereader` as *input* and will create a new PDF as *output* using the `writer`.

Comment: you are right. It was my mistake. but now I always get fields Count = 0. PDF template is not Empty Document.

Comment: There's a huge difference between an *empty document* and a document that doesn't contain any AcroForm fields. Maybe you see a form with your eyes, but that doesn't mean that a computer program can see those fields. Can you fill out the fields manually in a PDF viewer? If not, **then there are no fields!** If you can fill out the fields, then the AcroForm field count can still be 0 **if the form is a dynamic XFA form.** So the real question is: what type of form are you trying to fill out?

Comment: I use the `Foxit reader` as PDF viewer. Maybe it is really not a form. Actually I just want to override the Page Number.

Comment: Page numbers usually aren't stored in form fields. You should post a different question. This question was answered. The `PdfException` was solved, and should be accepted. "Rewriting page numbers in a PDF" is a much more difficult issue than "filling out form fields." I doubt if someone will be able to give you a good answer to that *second* (and *different*) question.